# Debug autorewrite in Coq

Tags: coq, tactic, usage, rewriting

I often meet proofs using `autorewrite` which Coq takes a while to process for some reason. (Setoid rewriting)
I then manually figure out which rewrite rules were applied and perform the steps manually or semi-automatically. Often applying `transitivity` or `Proper` by hand is quicker.

Is there some way to have Coq tell me which rules `autorewrite` applied? Possibly also how it instantiated the variables.

I found [issue #9285](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/9285), but it does not mention existing features.

Edit: Link to the relevant page of the reference manual on [Programmable Proof Search](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/auto.html)
where the `autorewrite` tactic is described.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `autorewrite` specifically, but in general one you have a proof term, you can `Print` it and figure out what automatic steps did in your back:

````
Lemma foo: forall n : nat, n = n.
Proof.
auto.
Qed.

Print foo. (* from this we know a proof is: intro n ; apply eq_refl *)
```
````

Comment: I tried to use this approach, but I find it impractical in my situation. setoid_rewrite is involved, with multiple nested `Proper` functions. This leads to large proof terms which are difficult to understand. If only equality were used, it might be easier.